# :first-letter selector working in Firefox not in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

How come this simple CSS works in FF but not in IE???

```
<style>

      .FirstLetter:first-letter{font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;color:White; background:Blue; border:1px black solid; padding-top:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom:3px;}
      .Spaced{letter-spacing: 5px;font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;}
      </style>

<div class="FirstLetter Spaced headerFont">
Executive Summary
</div>
```

here is an example if the two browsers showing different results on the first blue box of the lettering...
[image]

Comment: I wonder how many other questions have the exact same title... but yet the body of the question is totally unique...

Comment: in what ie version it doesn't work? I checked it in ie7,8 and looks fine

Comment: How many questions are there about IEs CSS quirks. Is what I meant...

Answer (score 0):

`FirstLetter:first-letter` selector if not completely supported by IE [reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter)

[image]

Comment: it works fine in IE. the blue ox around the first letter shows in IE and FF but in IE the box doesn't take the height and other formatting

Comment: I thought so too, but MSDN says that IE>6 supports `:first-letter` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: it is supported and working. the blue box around the first letter doesn't take shape properly, and the entire font size and weight is not adjusted in IE

Comment: -1 `:first-letter` it supported from ie 5.5 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: whats the CSS way of getting this to work in IE6 ? can i have a floating blue div? there has to be a way.

Comment: Use conditional css, with `padding: 5px 0px;` for IE6